# Problemas con inicio de sesion omniauth-facebook ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-api

estoy tratando de hacer una conexion con facebook y ruby on rails utilizando el omniauth-facebook, pero cuando trato de hacer una conexion me manda un error de **"no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"**,
seria de mucha ayuda si me pueden a clarar donde estoy cometiendo el error este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

en la carpeta initializers creo un archivo omniauth.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'xxxxface_book_idxxxxx', 'xxxsecret_id_facebookxxxxxx'
end
```

creo una ruta en routes.rb:

```
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

seguido de un controller sessions_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth("omniauth.auth")
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

luego creo un modelo llamado user.rb:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider,:uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

Luego en application_controller.rb :

```
private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
```

Luego agrego en application.html.erb:

```
<% if current_user%>
  Signed in as <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>
  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out"%>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in"%>
<% end %>
```

pero cuando hago click en el link me manda el error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna idea en donde puedo estar cometiendo el error???
realmente apreciare si me pueden ayudar con esto.

Answer (score 1):

No he usado `facebook-omniauth` antes, pero viendo la [documentación](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash) creo que tu error va por usar:

```
User.from_omniauth("omniauth.auth")
```

en vez de:

```
User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
```

entonces luego al llamar `auth.slice(:provider,:uid)` estás llamando al método `.slice` de [String](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/slice) que no permite símbolos en vez del de [Hash](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) que te retorna `request.env` que si los permite.

Comment: Hola ya agregue lo que me comentas  como : `provider :facebook, ENV['xxxx'], ENV['xxxxxx']` en el omniauth.rb y en session controller agrego `User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])` pero me manda el el mensaje : `Warning
The parameter app_id is required`

Comment: @JULIOMACHAN ¿Y estás seguro que efectivamente  `ENV['xxxx']` te está retornando el app_id ?

Comment: En efecto cuando paso el provider de esta forma no lo acepta `provider :facebook, ENV['xxfacebook_idxx'], ENV['xxfacebook_id_secretxx']` tiene que ser sin los ENV para que pase la informacion de esta forma `provider :facebook, 'xxfacebook_idxx', 'xxfacebook_id_secretxx'` y le agrego el `User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])` que comentaste pero al momento de hacer eso me manda esto : `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` marcando esta linea `where(auth.slice(:provider,:uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|`

Comment: @JULIOMACHAN Ese es ya otro error, el anterior se corrige con esta respuesta; lo correcto sería aceptarla y abrir una nueva pregunta con el problema que ahora describes.

Answer (score 0):

> me manda esto:
>
> `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`
>
> marcando esta linea:
>
> `where(auth.slice(:provider,:uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|`

Necesitas modificar el código para que *rails* pueda aceptar los atributos `provider` y `uid` correctamente.

Para solucionarlo cambia la línea que muestra el error por esta otra:

```
where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |user|
```

Comment: @JULIOMACHAN Esta respuesta debería solucionar tu segundo problema; aunque insisto en que deberías abrir otra pregunta para agregar esta respuesta ahí y ayudar a futuros desarrolladores que tengan este problema. Recuerda que SO runciona mejor con un problema por pregunta.